# how to add ngx_http_mp4_module to a heroku app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, nginx, mediaelement.js, pseudo-streaming

I need to add the following module to my app. 
[ngx_http_mp4_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html)
This is in order to pseudo-stream flash videos with mediaelement.

I am not sure how to proceed with this. Any guidance would be great.

Answer (score 4):

I was struggling over the same thing, it turns out it was very easy to fix with a single apt-get command.

Easy way: (On ubuntu);
Before:

```
$ nginx -t 
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "mp4" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.domain.eu:38 
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Apt-get the nginx-extras

```
$ sudo apt-get install nginx-extras
```

After

```
$ nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

(then, 'nginx -s reload' to activate as normal)

Other way: 
Nginx Modules need to be included at compile time
From: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html

> This module is not built by default, it should be enabled with the
>   --with-http_mp4_module configuration parameter.

This answer goes a long way to explain how to do it: https://serverfault.com/questions/342358/nginx-add-enable-mp4-module
and also gave me the apt-get nginx-extras solution I was looking for.